# Using if statement with evaluators in Overpass

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api, overpass-turbo, germany, if-statement

I am trying to query all the nodes which are in Potsdam city and with postcode 14480.

I know that it can be coded as follows:

```
    area["ISO3166-1"="DE"][admin_level=2]->.germany;
(
  node["addr:city"="Potsdam"]["addr:postcode"="14480"](area.germany);
)->.r;
```

but I would like to use an if condition with evaluators as shown below in the code.

However, it seems that there is something wrong in the code below
How can I fix it?

Code:

```
    [out:json][timeout:180];
area["ISO3166-1"="DE"]["admin_level"="2"]->.germany;
(
  node(
    if: (t["addr:city"] == "Potsdam") && (t["addr:postcode"] =="14480")
  );
);

  out geom;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first query does not return results for me.

When using the Overpass Turbo Wizard with the query "addr:postcode=14480 in Potsdam" it generates the following statement

```
/*
This has been generated by the overpass-turbo wizard.
The original search was:
“addr:postcode=14480 in Potsdam”
*/
[out:json][timeout:25];
// fetch area “Potsdam” to search in
{{geocodeArea:Potsdam}}->.searchArea;
// gather results
(
  // query part for: “"addr:postcode"=14480”
  node["addr:postcode"="14480"](area.searchArea);
);
// print results
out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```

See here: https://overpass-turbo.eu/s/14NY .

The result seem to be correct this way.