# How to use if statement to check if a tag is assigned to particular value

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api, overpass-turbo

I would like to filter out areas in Germany with post code = 14480. I coded the lines posted below
but when I run it returns nothing.
How can I fix this?

Code:

```
[timeout:3600];
area["ISO3166-1"="DE"][admin_level=2]->.germany;
foreach .germany -> .reg (
  node.germany(if: t["addr:postcode"] == reg.u(t["addr:postcode"]))
  ->.targetArea;
  node.targetArea(if: node.targetArea["addr:postcode"] == "14480");
  out geom;


);
  out;
```

Comment: Please don't post multiple variants of the same question [How to use if statement with evaluators](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/389314/how-to-use-if-statement-with-evaluators)

Comment: Why would you use if statements? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: what i want to achieve is when the tag addr:postcode is available then check if it is equal to 14480